# Run Sagemaker notebook instance and be able to close tab

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I'm currently using Sagemaker notebook instance (not from Sagemaker Studio), and I want to run a notebook that is expected to take around 8 hours to finish. I want to leave it overnight, and see the output from each cell, the output is a combination of print statements and plots.

Howevever, when I start running the notebook and make sure the initial cells run, I close the Jupyterlab tab in my browser, and some minutes after, I open it again to see how is it going, but the notebook is stopped.

Is there any way where I can still use my notebook as it is, see the output from each cell (prints and plots) and do not have to keep the Jupyterlab tab open (turn my laptop off, etc)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If I close my JupyterLab from notebook instance, would my code be gone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67210677/if-i-close-my-jupyterlab-from-notebook-instance-would-my-code-be-gone)

Comment: Not entirely, I did look at it and was helpful if my output was only print statements, and I have also plots in my output.

Comment: If that's the main issue, you could save the plots as images and retrieve them later from the results in S3 with the method I linked to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question.

I ended up using Sagemaker Processing jobs for this. As initially suggested by the other answer. I found this library developed a few months ago: [Sagemaker run notebook](https://github.com/aws-samples/sagemaker-run-notebook), which helped still keep my notebook structure and cells as I had them, and be able to run it using Sagemaker run notebook using a bigger instance, and modifying the notebook in a smaller one.

The output of each cell was saved, along the plots I had, in S3 as a jupyter notebook.

I see that no constant support is given to the library, but you can fork it and make changes to it, and use it as per your requirements. For example, creating a docker container based on your needs.

Comment: Can you show the gist of the sh file that you have set up in your Sagemaker instance for the lifecycle config? I have tried using the config file, but it showed the following error `The module 'jupyter_server_terminals' could not be found (No module named 'jupyter_server_terminals'). Are you sure the extension is installed?`

Answer (score 4):

Jupyter will stop your kernel when you close the tab. If you want to benefit from your jobs running after you close the jupyter tab, I would recommend looking into using SageMaker Processing or Training jobs for your workloads. Alternatively, [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/keep-jupyter-notebook-running-even-after-browser-is-closed-9a1937b7c615) link provides some options on how to keep the notebook running with the tab closed.